# How to generate the result of bigrams with highest probabilities with a list of individual alphabetical strings as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, probability

I am learning natural language processing for bigram topic. At this stage, I am having difficulty in the Python computation, but I try.

I will be using this corpus that has not been subjected to tokenization as my main raw dataset. I can generate the bigram results using nltk module. However, my question is how to compute in Python to generate the bigrams containing more than two specific words. More specifically, I wish to find all the bigrams, which are available in corpus_A, that contain words from the word_of_interest.

> > > corpus = ["he is not giving up so easily but he feels lonely all the time his mental is strong and he always meet new friends to get motivation and inspiration to success he stands firm for academic integrity when he was young he hope that santa would give him more friends after he is a grown up man he stops wishing for santa clauss to arrival  he and his friend always eat out but they clean their hand to remove sand first before eating"]
> > >
> > > word_of_interest = ['santa', 'and', 'hand', 'stands', 'handy', 'sand']

I want to get the bigram for each of the individual words from the list of word_of_interest. Next, I want to get the frequency for each bigram available based on their appearance in the corpus_A. With the frequency available, I want to sort and print out the bigram based on their probability from highest to lower.

I have tried out codes from on-line search but it does not give me an output. The codes are mentioned below:

```
for i in corpus:
    bigrams_i = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus, window_size=5)
    bigram_j = lambda i[x] not in i
    x += 1
print(bigram_j)
```

Unfortunately, the output did not return what I am planning to achieve.

Please advice me. The output that I want will have the bigram with the specific words from the word_of_interest and their probabilities sorted as shown below.

```
[((santa, clauss), 0.89), ((he, and), 0.67), ((stands, firm), 0.34))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2),use_idf=False)

corpus = ["he is not giving up so easily but he feels lonely all the time his mental is strong and he always meet new friends to get motivation and inspiration to success he stands firm for academic integrity when he was young he hope that santa would give him more friends after he is a grown up man he stops wishing for santa clauss to arrival he and his friend always eat out but they clean their hand to remove sand first before eating"]
word_of_interest = ['santa', 'and', 'hand', 'stands', 'handy', 'sand']
matrix = vec.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
vocabulary = vec.get_feature_names()

all_bigrams = []
all_frequencies = []
for word in word_of_interest:
    for bigram in vocabulary:
        if word in bigram:
            index = vocabulary.index(bigram)
            tuple_bigram = tuple(bigram.split(' '))
            frequency = matrix[:,index].sum()
            all_bigrams.append(tuple_bigram)
            all_frequencies.append(frequency)

df = pd.DataFrame({'bigram':all_bigrams,'frequency':all_frequencies})
df.sort_values('frequency',inplace=True)
df.head()
```

The output is a pandas dataframe showing the bigrams sorted by frequency.

```
    bigram  frequency
0     (for, santa)   0.109764
19  (stands, firm)   0.109764
18    (he, stands)   0.109764
17   (their, hand)   0.109764
16      (hand, to)   0.109764
```

The rationale here is that TfidfVectorizer counts how many times a token is present in each document of a corpus, then computes the term-specific frequency, and then stores this information in a column associated with that token. The index of that column is the same as the index of the associated word in the vocabulary that is retrieved with the method .get_feature_names() on the vectorizer already fit.
Then you just have to select all rows from the matrix containing the relative frequencies of the tokens, and sum along the column of interest.

The double-nested for loop is not ideal though, and there may be a more efficient implementation for it. The issue is that get_feature_names returns not tuples, but a list of strings in the form ['first_token second_token',].
I would be interested in seeing a better implementation of the second half of the above code.